# UPDATE in mysql using python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, sql-update

how to do Update in mysql consider Rate is int(8)

```
k=int(4000);

db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","pass,"databse")

cursor=db.cursor()

sql="UPDATE tablename SET Rate=k WHERE  Name='xxx'

cursor=db.cursor()

try:
      cursor.execute(sql)
      db.commit()
except:
    db.rollback()

db.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sql` should be:

```
sql = "UPDATE tablename SET Rate = (%s) WHERE Name='xxx'"
```

and then you should do:

```
cursor.execute(sql,(k,))
```

note that `k` needs to be in a container to be passed correctly to `.execute()`. in this case it is a tuple.

also `int(4000)` is redundant. you can just do: `k = 4000`

if you also want to pass in the name you can do:

```
sql = "UPDATE tablename SET Rate = (%s) WHERE Name=(%s)"
```

and then:

```
cursor.execute(sql,(k,name))
```

Comment: What about numeric data, `%g`. `%s` would go for string I guess. Documentation pls. Thanks.

Comment: @ankit7540: all data types use `%s`; that's just how the library works.